# What does it mean by subtract half of the form/s?

Tags: c#

I have this constructor in my new Form:

```
public MagnifierForm(Point MousePosition)
        {
            _doMove = true;
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            ShowInTaskbar = false;
            TopMost = true;
            Width = 150;
            Height = 150;
            GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
            gp.AddEllipse(ClientRectangle);
            Region = new Region(gp);
            mTimer = new Timer();
            mTimer.Enabled = true;
            mTimer.Interval = 20;
            mTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(HandleTimer);
            mScreenImage = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                     Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

            //maybe subtract half of the forms width/height from the points (offset them)
            mStartPoint = MousePosition;
            mTargetPoint = MousePosition;
            speed = 0.35F;
        }
```

On the bottom of the constructor i have added this code:

```
mStartPoint = MousePosition;
mTargetPoint = MousePosition;
```

In Form1 i have this code:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.M))
            {
                if (mf == null)
                {
                    mf = new Magnifier20070401.MagnifierForm(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);
                    mf.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                    mf.Location = Control.MousePosition;
                    mf.Show();

                    this.Select();
                }
                else if (mf.IsDisposed)
                {
                    mf = new Magnifier20070401.MagnifierForm(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);
                    mf.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                    mf.Location = Control.MousePosition;
                    mf.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    mf.Close();
                    mf = null;
                }
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

Everything is working fine.
And this mStartPoint wich set the position/location fo the form also working good.

But what the sentence mean ? //maybe subtract half of the forms width/height from the points (offset them)

The sentecense is something to do with the : mStartPoint and mTargetPoint

Can someone show me an example how it should look like if i want to make use this sentence ?

Comment: Is this your code?  It looks like another developer left a comment in there to remind themselves to look at an alternative way of doing whatever the code is doing?

Comment: I guess by half of the form it means (this.window.height/2) and (this.window.width/2)...right Ben???

Comment: Would be very funny to see own peace of code (with own comments lol) some day here. How about asking guy who wrote that part in personal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this thread was originally [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3642e79b-066b-4e2f-bd28-4e8c1cb021ed).

Following the previous line:

```
mScreenImage = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                     Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
```

I think the writer was saying you should compute the part of the captured form to show at the start by dividing the form's width and height in other to know which part to show. If your code is correct, I assume there is somewhere you are computing the part of the form that needs to be shown and the varying sizes for different magnifications.